# Problema con scanf en strings

Tags: c

```
char palabra [20];

char letra;

printf("Ejercicio para eliminar un caracter de una palabra\n");
fflush(stdout);

printf("Introduzca la palabra deseada:\n");
fflush(stdout);
gets(palabra);
//scanf("%s",palabra);



printf("Introduzca el caracter deseado:\n");
fflush(stdout);
scanf("%c",&letra);


quitacaracter(palabra,letra);

return 0;
```

Estaba intentando realizar un codigo que lea un string y un caracter y devuelva ese string sin el caracter introducido, pues bien al leer el string con gets todo perfecto pero cuando lo leo con scanf("%s",palabra) se salta la lectura del caracter y no logro solucionarlo.

Comment: ¿Qué resultados obtienes? ¿Qué resultados esperas? ¿Qué contiene la definición de la función `quitacaracter`? ¿Ya te pasaste por el [tour]? Así te haces una idea más clara de como funciona el sitio y ganes tu primera medalla :D, de paso pasate por [ask] para que nos ayudes a aydarte!!! Saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Para evitar ese problema añade un espacio a la lectura del caracter:

```
scanf(" %c",&letra);
//     ^
```

De esta forma `scanf` descartará sin problemas el salto de línea... de haberlo. Si no hay salto de línea también funcionará.